# Linear transformation $T(x) =Ax,$ where $A$ is a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

In the linear transformation $T(x)=Ax$ where A is a suitable matrix, does the transformation map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ or does it map from a matrix space to another matrix space?

Comment: it maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to  $\mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "matrix space." But $T$ maps the *vector* space $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: You ask the same question again. Try a look at 3blue1brown [Essence of linear algebra](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) playlist for understand those transformation